# comparing $injector and injector created explicitly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var explicitInjector = angular.injector(['myApp'], true);
console.log('modchk outside ctrler', explicitInjector);
myApp.service('serv', function() {});

var x = angular.injector(['myApp'], true);

function MyCtrl1($scope, $injector) {
  $scope.result = JSON.stringify($injector) == JSON.stringify(explicitInjector);
  $scope.value1 = $injector.has('serv');
  $scope.value2 = explicitInjector.has('serv');
}
myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', MyCtrl1);
```

```html
<html ng-app='myApp'>

  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div1" ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
      <P>(JSON.stringify($injector)==JSON.stringify(explicitInjector))={{result}}
        <hr>
        <p>injector as argument to the controller($inject)={{value1}}</p>
        <hr>
        <p>injector from outside the controller(angular.injector())={{value2}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here i'm trying to create an injector outside controller using `angular.injector()` by name **explicitInjector** and inside controller i'm getting `$injector` and on comparing both object contents are showing same.
when i try to check the service present using `.has()` from both of there it is showing `true` with $injector and `false` with explicitInjector where it should have given `true`.Help me out in this,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UAVLTig4k2iZ1vLbt03B?p=preview

- I changed the version to 1.5.8
- used ===

The `{{result}}` comparison fails, which explains why the property is not found in explicitInjector.

Comment: in recent yrs. thats the most stable version of Ang. 1. and pretty stable n predicatable. Any version above it is fine as well. The context for that particular injection was not getting preserved rightly in 1.4.x , which is what explains why this happened. I would suggest u to migrate to any version above 1.5.8 to use new features like components, etc.